# Triggering method when element is added to the document

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to implement a placeholder feature for IE.

So far I have got the following code:

```
if(!$.support.placeholder) {

    $('#closestStaticParent').on('focus', '[placeholder]' function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
      }
    }).on('blur', '[placeholder]' function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).blur();

}
```

So it adds the placeholder on blur and the code blurs every element with placeholder.
The issue now is that only initially loaded elements blurs. If I load textfields with ajax, they do not trigger `blur()`.

How do I make so that new textfields initiate `blur()` on themselves when they are added to the document (loaded)?

PS. Please no answers with time-interval-based or ajax-success re-checks.

Comment: You could have a class that the new elements would have to have, and then attach the event, then strip the class after or leave it.

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#closestStaticParent')` to `$('body')`  if the elements you are creating are not a child of `closestStaticParent`

Comment: they are children of `closestStaticParent`